# Reopening a question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-close, re-open

Is it  a  good idea to reopen this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184820/a-metric-on-s2)? I really can not get  a  complete answer from some comments on (the  final version) of the question.

Comment: What is your exact question here? The question in the title and the one below it seem quite different, and I'm not sure what you want to know. The fact that your question was closed suggests that the answer to the second question is "yes".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta it depends on the opinion of  various  participants not  just 5 people who voted to close. My question is  that "is  not  a  good idea to reopen this question?

Comment: I see. I suggest editing that to the body of your question, so that it is clear what kind of answers you are looking for. Asking whether or not a closed question is worth reopening sounds reasonable to me, but I first thought you meant something else.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I also add that, according to  some comments to this  question which count this  question as  an exercise Iwould like to ask "was it realy  a simple exercise?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Now I  understand what you mean. thanks

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I edited it. thanks  again.

Answer (score 7):

It's generally a complete disaster when someone asks a question, has it answered via an trivial comment, and then changes the question to the question 'they really wanted to ask'.

To anyone coming along later, it's near impossible to understand what's going on. It's nearly always best, if your initial question turns out to be broken in some way, to say thanks, and post an entirely new question (hopefully with at least a comment below it explaining that this is the question you really meant to ask all along, with a link, and explanation, of the previous broken question).

(The automatically added notice on closed questions, encouraging you to edit if possible, is basically unhelpful and inappropriate on MathOverflow.)

Comment: Well -- I think this depends on the particular case. Posting a new question just because one has forgotten to exclude some trivial case seems not reasonable to me -- in that case I think it is best to fix the question and the commenter who has highlighted the omission removes their now outdated comment.

Comment: I think the record of the process should be made visible, with acknowledgment of refining comments.  Even if the first question was poor, it often is what occurs in initial approaches to a topic; the refining comments help steer a newcomer in the right direction, especially when the newcomer has arrived late to the party.